# Past tense of RSVP

Tags: tenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Past participle of a verb created from an acronym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/past-participle-of-a-verb-created-from-an-acronym)

Since RSVP has morphed into a verb, I was wondering the correct way of using its past tense.

"Only 1 person RSVP'd to my event."

"Only 1 person did RSVP to my event."

"Only 1 person RSVPed to my event."

Which is correct, or if they are all incorrect, what is the correct way?

Comment: That question doesn't seem to answer my question. It seems to be subjective.

Comment: In that case, also the answer reported here is subjective. The question is still a duplicate, as there is already a question asking the same topic.

Comment: The answer isn't what I was looking for and at the bottom of all questions it says, "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged *participle *acronyms or ask your own question." So I asked my own question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In formulating past tenses of unlikely words or acronyms, an *apostrophe-d* is always used to prevent confusion or mispronunciation. (Obviously this is non-issue in speech.) You could also use the auxiliary *do* if you want to avoid this construction. These two sentences are thus correct:

> - Only one person RSVP'd to my event.
> - Only one person did RSVP to my event.

Also, keep in mind that whenever acronyms are put in past tense using the *apostrophe-d* formulation, no account is taken of the full logical meaning of the acronym. Thus, you have examples like

- *DIY'd* (which means *engaged in a DIY project* or *carried out DIY on*, etc),
- *BS'd*,
- *SWAK'd* (*sealed with a kiss*),

and so forth.

*RSVP* (*Répondez S'il Vous Plaît* — *reply if you please/please reply*) is a special acronym because it functions as a verb. However, we have all found it convenient to take it away from its largely stiff, formal original context (e.g. *RSVP: Mr. Jones*) to more useful ones, such as:

> - Don't forget to RSVP.
> - I did not RSVP. Can I still come?
> - Anyone planning to come should RSVP, so I know how many burgers to buy.
> - Please RSVP ASAP! (*never mind the repetition!*)

The past tense is less common, but *RSVP'd* would be the *correct* way to write it down.

Answer (score -1):

RSVP is what you put at the bottom of an invitation, and means "please reply".

I don't think many people are likely to say "I didn't *please reply* to the invitation".

Better to just say "I didn't reply".

Comment: "RSVP" has a specific meaning in English compared to just "reply."

Comment: Indeed it has, and that specific meaning means that it is /Only/ used at the bottom of invitations, and not outside of that context.

If you answer an FAQ, you don't say "I FAQ-ed", you say "I answered", and if you respond to an invitation, you don't say "I RSPV-ed", you say "I responded".

One of the biggest problems the English language has is that of people trying to invent rules to allow them to continue to make stupid mistakes.