# Proper to add tense to acronyms, abbreviations and initialisms

Tags: verbs, abbreviations, acronyms, tenses, initialisms

[What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym) asked about pluralising acronyms, abbreviations and initialisms, but is there a standard way to add verb endings e.g. -ing and -ed (what are these called?), at least in informal English?

For example, which of these is/are best?

1. I'm SMSing her.
2. I'm SMS-ing her.
3. I'm SMS'ing her.

I know I can rephrase it to "I'm sending her an SMS." but I wish to use SMS as a verb.

Similarly,

1. He FUBARed.
2. He FUBAR-ed.
3. He FUBAR'ed.
4. He FUBAR-d.
5. He FUBAR'd.

In the latter set, as the verb is actually the F ("foul", or something more explicit) — the expanded sentence being "He fouled up beyond all recognition." — should it even be "He FedUBAR." or similar?

Comment: The best way to spell "SMSing" in English is "texting". And the term you are looking for is [*suffix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix).

Comment: It seems odd that you would say "someone fucked up beyond all recognition", surely they *are* in that state, they don't *do* that state. So "He was FUBARd". But that's just a niggle.

Comment: Well, then again, "someone fucked up beyond all recognition" is a valid phrase in and of itself, if "fucked up" is taken to be a verb rather than an adjective.

Comment: @JoeZ. I have to agree with Matt. FUBAR is an adjectival phrase; here, "beyond all recognition" means "into an unrecognizable form." It's an intensification of SNAFU ("situation normal, all fucked up"). If SNAFU gets even worse, it's FUBAR. If you convert it (but why?) to verb form ("he fucked up"), you wouldn't use "beyond all recognition" to hyperbolize it. To hyperbolize this version, you would need a phrase like "beyond anything he's ever done before." (By the way, these are ironic acronyms of WWII vintage, and losing some popularity with age, sorry to say.)

Comment: I can't think of any way to use _-ed_ or _-ing_ as a valid suffix. Can anyone else? _-d_ simply doesn't exist, and _'d_ is archaic (no longer used). If you must use these as verbs, go ahead and use the _ed_ or _ing_ with no punctuation. But tell me, why are you so gung-ho to use these as verbs?

Comment: You get to be creative.  If you set a trend, in 10 years the dictionary will show the approach you chose.  I personally like fubarred.  For sms and -ing, I would have trouble proposing something specific.  That combination does not roll off my tongue, so I don't have the creative motivation needed.  But you do, so go wild.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Past participle of a verb created from an acronym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/past-participle-of-a-verb-created-from-an-acronym)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg: [Multiple style manual recommend *'d* for making verb acronyms/initialisms past tense](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/do-you-use-apostrophe-make-%E2%80%9Cok%E2%80%9D-past-tense) so I wouldn't call it archaic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a non-verb acronym or initialism as a verb, you're already in the realm of jargon. If you're writing in a context where that's acceptable, you should add a simple "ed" or "ing" for a suffix unless you're going for a humorous effect. When acronyms are absorbed into the language, they may acquire verb forms; for example, the verb meaning "to produce a laser beam" is "lase," retroactively treating the acronym for "light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation" as if it meant "something that 'lases.'"

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on context, in my case I use an apostrophe as needed.

- *SMSed* looks fine to me.
- *MACing*, however, sounds like we're using a mace (weapon/spray) on someone. For such case I would go with *MAC'ing*¹ which makes the intent clearer.

¹ MAC is [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)

<sub><sup>P.S. I'm not from the realm of languages, but wanted to add some additional info on what I do in practice.</sup></sub>