# Past tense of MOT?

Tags: tenses, suffixes, acronyms, initialisms

I'm usually quite good at this kind of thing but can't decide on this.

When describing when a car has had its MOT (Ministry of Transport) test do I write...

1. Recently MOTd
2. Recently MOT'd
3. Recently MOTed

...or something else? All of them look a bit wrong but a bit right.

Or do I just cop out and put "Recently MOT Tested" instead???

Most Google searches bring up results for "Match of the Day"!

Comment: What does MOT stand for? Often the answer depends on the actual phrase being abbreviated.

Comment: @jimm101 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOT_test

Comment: "Ministry of Transport". There's no verb, so unless there's an accepted convention that has evolved over time, "MOT tested" would be clear. Sometimes quirks develop (IP protocol is redundant to Internet Protocol Protocol, but is widely used), but short of a standard in the field, I wouldn't create a new convention. This would be a different conversation if the T stood for "Tested".

Comment: @jimm101 It's actually just "Ministry of Transport" but that magically turns into a verb when you make it an acronym and apply it to testing a car. When spoken it's always said as "MOTd" and never "MOT Tested".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/past-participle-of-a-verb-created-from-an-acronym

Comment: @AndyO Our doctors' surgery offered annual basic medical tests, which they used to refer to as an MOT. "Come in and have an MOT", they used to say. But for some reason they've stopped calling them that. But I never remember telling anyone I'd been MOT'd!

Comment: @WS2 People were probably scared of failing the emissions test.

Comment: Nobody MOTs grammatically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a NARQ.

Answer (score 2):

Your second choice appears to be correct.

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mot) suggests the use of an apostrophe:

> MOTing, MOT'd, MOT'd
>
> I want to get/have the car **MOT'd** before we drive to France.

[Autoexpress.co.uk](https://www.autoexpress.co.uk/car-news/100726/how-to-check-if-a-car-is-taxed-mot-d-and-insured)'s article - "How to check if a car is taxed, **MoT’d** and insured" follows suit.

and

[The Money Advice Service](https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/blog/new-mot-vehicle-test-may-2018) confirms this use

> If your MOT results show a dangerous fault, you won’t be able to drive it anywhere. This doesn’t mean you have to have the repairs carried out at the garage that **MOT’d** it, though.
>
> You should get a quote for the work that needs to be done for the car to **MOT’d** at the garage you’re at, and then find a few others and see how much they’d charge. You might find, even with a towing fee, you can get it fixed for less.

Comment: I'll encourage the querent to go with the dictionary, as you've pointed out here - but I'll also note that my own inclination would have been to go with _MOTted_.

Comment: I guess the apostrophe in "MOT'd" is instead of putting "MOTed"? So two out of my three options were useable?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: that would only make sense if "MOT" were pronounced to rhyme with "pot". But it isn't, in my experience, ever. It's "emm-oh-tee".

Comment: @ColinFine - That's probably my US-ism showing; while the equivalent here in most states is "emissions testing" (and done as part of "inspection", meaning vehicle safety inspection/verification), there's also a tendency to pronounce acronyms that look pronounceable - so "MOT" probably would become "mot, rhyming with pot", just like DoITT (Department of Information Technology and Telecommunications) has become "do it".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: that's what I guessed. I think "MOT test" became established in speech before people saw it written very often.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to say "Recent MOT."

Or "MOT June 2018" which informs others exactly when you obtained the MOT.